# Consumer application causing duplicate while reading records from multiple partition

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to consume record from stream using spring-kafka. The records are in the avro schema. As there are 2 partitions on the topic, I am using kafka concurrency as 2 to consume records from partitions in parallel. But, it seems it is causing some issue.

I am logging received record from partition before processing to make sure we are not getting duplicate ( same key in different partition).

**Configuration :**

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory(){
        
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,KAFKA_BROKERS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OFFSET_RESET);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID_CONFIG);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, MAX_POLL_RECORDS);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, MAX_POLL_INTERVAL);
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, SSL_PROTOCOL);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_TRUSTSTORE_SECURE);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_KEYSTORE_SECURE);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_KEY_SECURE);
        
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);    
    }
    
    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> 
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
 
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory =
                            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
      factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
      factory.setConcurrency(KAFKA_CONCURRENCY);
      factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE); // manual async committ
      //factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO)
      return factory;
  }
```

**Code :**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic}", groupId = "${app.group_id_config}")
    public void run(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgement) throws Exception {

        try {
            //System.out.println(record);
            if (record.value().get("enrollmentType").toString().matches("ACH|VCP|CHK")) 
            {
                prov_tin_number         = record.value().get("providerTinNumber").toString();
                //prov_tin_type             = record.value().get("providerTINType").toString();
                enroll_type             = record.value().get("enrollmentType").toString();
                vcp_prov_choice_ind     = record.value().get("vcpProvChoiceInd").toString();
                error_flag              = "";
        
        
            } 
            
            
                System.out.println("coming from stream :" + prov_tin_number + " into offset " + record.offset() + " and partition " + record.partition());
                
        
                
            
            acknowledgement.acknowledge();
                
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(record);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

**Output from Code :**

**Example :**

```
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 500428 and partition 0
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499553 and partition 1
```

It seems from above output, same record is coming into different offset and partition and causing duplicate at consumer end. But, this is not the case, when I am trying to read record using command line, I am getting below output :

```
root@fast-data-dev bin $ kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2 --bootstrap-server kaas-test-ctc-a.optum.com:443 --consumer.config
/data/test/client-test-ssl.properties **--partition 1 --offset 499553**  --property schema.registry.url="http://kaas-test-schema-registry.com" --max-messages 1
{"**providerTinNumber":"018601027"**,"providerTINType":"TIN","enrollmentType":"ACH","vcpProvChoiceInd":{"string":"null"},"usrDefFld1":null,"usrDefFld2":null,"usrDefFld3":null,"usrDefFld4":null,"usrDefFld5":null,"usrDefFld6":null,"usrDefFld7":null,"usrDefFld8":null,"usrDefFld9":null,"usrDefFld10":null}
Processed a total of 1 messages
root@fast-data-dev bin $ kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2 --bootstrap-server kaas-test-ctc-a.optum.com:443 --consumer.config
/data/test/client-test-ssl.properties **--partition 0 --offset 500428** --property schema.registry.url="http://kaas-test-schema-registry.com" --max-messages 1
{"**providerTinNumber":"024580061"**,"providerTINType":"TIN","enrollmentType":"ACH","vcpProvChoiceInd":{"string":"null"},"usrDefFld1":null,"usrDefFld2":null,"usrDefFld3":null,"usrDefFld4":null,"usrDefFld5":null,"usrDefFld6":null,"usrDefFld7":null,"usrDefFld8":null,"usrDefFld9":null,"usrDefFld10":null}
Processed a total of 1 messages
```

we do have different values on different offsets and partition. It's clearly visible there is something wrong in my code and it's not happening for just 1 record but multiple.

Full Spring boot log :

```
00:26:11.507 [restartedMain] INFO  com.emerald.peconsumer.ApplicationRun - Started ApplicationRun in 2.896 seconds (JVM running for 12.571)
00:26:13.357 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Cluster ID: 6cbv7QOaSW6j1vXrOCE4jA
00:26:13.357 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Cluster ID: 6cbv7QOaSW6j1vXrOCE4jA
00:26:13.359 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Discovered group coordinator apslp1563.uhc.com:9093 (id: 2147483574 rack: null)
00:26:13.359 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Discovered group coordinator apslp1563.uhc.com:9093 (id: 2147483574 rack: null)
00:26:13.521 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
00:26:13.521 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
00:26:15.196 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
00:26:15.197 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
00:26:30.504 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Finished assignment for group at generation 77: {consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2-d2f920dc-a52a-4ed4-aa0f-1e3ef268a4fc=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerPartitionAssignor$Assignment@1f9e0b89, consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1-242f32f2-b823-4946-be1f-a6c584a0f3ce=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerPartitionAssignor$Assignment@91e5bc9}
00:26:30.815 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Successfully joined group with generation 77
00:26:30.815 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Successfully joined group with generation 77
00:26:30.818 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Adding newly assigned partitions: kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-0
00:26:30.818 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Adding newly assigned partitions: kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-1
00:26:31.133 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Setting offset for partition kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=500428, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=apslp1559.uhc.com:9093 (id: 69 rack: null), epoch=37}}
00:26:31.133 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Setting offset for partition kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=499553, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=apslp1562.uhc.com:9093 (id: 72 rack: null), epoch=36}}
00:26:31.134 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - csp-prov-emerald-test: partitions assigned: [kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-0]
00:26:31.134 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - csp-prov-emerald-test: partitions assigned: [kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-1]
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 500428 and partition 0
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499553 and partition 1
```

**Update :**

I tried to print records again with 1 consumer thread and 2 consumer thread.

**Output from 2 consumer thread :**

You can observe the randomness in behaviour.

Duplicate record : Same record is coming into 2 different partition

***First run :***

```
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 500428 and partition 0 <-- duplicate 
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499553 and partition 1 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :072461600 into offset 500429 and partition 0
coming from stream :027400400 into offset 499554 and partition 1
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 500430 and partition 0 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 499555 and partition 1 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 500431 and partition 0
coming from stream :052407795 into offset 499556 and partition 1
coming from stream :086586131 into offset 499557 and partition 1
coming from stream :113424057 into offset 500432 and partition 0
coming from stream :090443768 into offset 499558 and partition 1
coming from stream :024580061 into offset 500433 and partition 0
coming from stream :072461600 into offset 500434 and partition 0
coming from stream :090465976 into offset 499559 and partition 1
coming from stream :094324212 into offset 499560 and partition 1
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 500435 and partition 0
coming from stream :107422748 into offset 499561 and partition 1
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 500436 and partition 0
coming from stream :004582777 into offset 499562 and partition 1
coming from stream :113424057 into offset 500437 and partition 0
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499563 and partition 1
coming from stream :027400400 into offset 499564 and partition 1
coming from stream :031866294 into offset 499565 and partition 1
coming from stream :052407795 into offset 499566 and partition 1
coming from stream :086586131 into offset 499567 and partition 1
coming from stream :090443768 into offset 499568 and partition 1
coming from stream :090465976 into offset 499569 and partition 1
coming from stream :094324212 into offset 499570 and partition 1
coming from stream :107422748 into offset 499571 and partition 1
coming from stream :272626998 into offset 499572 and partition 1
```

***Second run :***

```
 coming from stream :024580061 into offset 499553 and partition 1 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :024580061 into offset 500428 and partition 0 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :027400400 into offset 499554 and partition 1
coming from stream :072461600 into offset 500429 and partition 0
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 500430 and partition 0
coming from stream :031866294 into offset 499555 and partition 1
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 500431 and partition 0
coming from stream :052407795 into offset 499556 and partition 1
coming from stream :113424057 into offset 500432 and partition 0
coming from stream :086586131 into offset 499557 and partition 1
coming from stream :090443768 into offset 499558 and partition 1
coming from stream :024580061 into offset 500433 and partition 0
coming from stream :072461600 into offset 500434 and partition 0
coming from stream :090465976 into offset 499559 and partition 1
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 500435 and partition 0
coming from stream :094324212 into offset 499560 and partition 1
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 500436 and partition 0 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 499561 and partition 1 <-- duplicate
coming from stream :004582777 into offset 499562 and partition 1
coming from stream :113424057 into offset 500437 and partition 0
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499563 and partition 1
coming from stream :027400400 into offset 499564 and partition 1
coming from stream :031866294 into offset 499565 and partition 1
coming from stream :052407795 into offset 499566 and partition 1
coming from stream :086586131 into offset 499567 and partition 1
coming from stream :090443768 into offset 499568 and partition 1
coming from stream :090465976 into offset 499569 and partition 1
coming from stream :094324212 into offset 499570 and partition 1
coming from stream :107422748 into offset 499571 and partition 1
coming from stream :272626998 into offset 499572 and partition 1
```

**Output from 1 consumer thread :**

No duplicate if using 1 consumer thread. The records are getting printed as expected. Does it mean the spring-kafka concurrency parameter is not reliable ? then how can I scale the consumer application to process records in parallel ?

```
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499553 and partition 1
coming from stream :027400400 into offset 499554 and partition 1
coming from stream :031866294 into offset 499555 and partition 1
coming from stream :052407795 into offset 499556 and partition 1
coming from stream :086586131 into offset 499557 and partition 1
coming from stream :090443768 into offset 499558 and partition 1
coming from stream :090465976 into offset 499559 and partition 1
coming from stream :094324212 into offset 499560 and partition 1
coming from stream :107422748 into offset 499561 and partition 1
coming from stream :004582777 into offset 499562 and partition 1
coming from stream :018601027 into offset 499563 and partition 1
coming from stream :027400400 into offset 499564 and partition 1
coming from stream :031866294 into offset 499565 and partition 1
coming from stream :052407795 into offset 499566 and partition 1
coming from stream :086586131 into offset 499567 and partition 1
coming from stream :090443768 into offset 499568 and partition 1
coming from stream :090465976 into offset 499569 and partition 1
coming from stream :094324212 into offset 499570 and partition 1
coming from stream :107422748 into offset 499571 and partition 1
coming from stream :272626998 into offset 499572 and partition 1
coming from stream :024580061 into offset 500428 and partition 0
coming from stream :072461600 into offset 500429 and partition 0
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 500430 and partition 0
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 500431 and partition 0
coming from stream :113424057 into offset 500432 and partition 0
coming from stream :024580061 into offset 500433 and partition 0
coming from stream :072461600 into offset 500434 and partition 0
coming from stream :090341206 into offset 500435 and partition 0
coming from stream :113423162 into offset 500436 and partition 0
coming from stream :113424057 into offset 500437 and partition 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a thread-safetly problem in code you are calling from your listener; when using multiple threads, you must not use fields, unless you protect them with synchronization logic.

e.g.

```java
public class NotThreadSafe {

    String someValue;

    void processRecord(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {

        this.someValue = record.value();

        doSomeMoreWork();
    
    }

    void doSomeMoreWork() {
        ...
        doSomethingWith(this.someValue);
    }

}
```

When there are multiple threads, one thread might see `someValue` from another thread.

Comment: You need to fix the code to make it thread-safe or only use one thread. You can also use `synchronized` blocks, if the shared state is only used for a small part of the logic. But that might end up defeating the multi-threading if you need a lot of synchronization. It's best to rework the logic so that no shared state exists. In the example above, you should pass `someValue` as a parameter instead of using a field.